# In Magento when I install a new brands extension I get an error?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am beginner in Magento. When I install a new brands-logo-extension I get an error.

Extension url is :http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manufacturer-brand-logo.html

and the error code is:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:88:"Invalid method Bc_Manufacturer_Block_Manufacturer::displayOnLeftSidebarBlock(Array
(

)
)";i:1;s:2503:"#0 [internal function]: Varien_Object->__call('displayOnLeftSi...', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Bc_Manufacturer_Block_Manufacturer->displayOnLeftSidebarBlock()
#2 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#4 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'furniture-jupit...')
#9 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'furniture-jupit...')
#10 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/jenadm/public_html/site.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps that we need to make changes in code after installation of that extension?? If NO, see the overview block in the extension page

Comment: can u send me links where in this extension write  overview block

Answer (score 0):

These are the details that are mentioned in the overview block. Please check the overview block and reviews  block before installing an extension.

**Below mentioned is the code you need to use for displaying brand logo on product detail page**

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manufacturer/manufacturer')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('manufacturer/product_manufacturer.phtml')->toHtml();
```

The magento extension also provides a block which displays the entire brand logos list in one page. You can use this code wherever you want the list to be displayed.

Code :

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('manufacturer/manufacturer')->setTemplate('manufacturer/manufacturer.phtml')->toHtml();
```